# jQuery UI Slider Not Appearing

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I thought the basic syntax for a slider was:

```
<div id="slider"></div>

$("#slider").slider()
```

But that doesn't make a visible slider.  Inspecting the `div` element, I see that some stylings were applied, but the slider isn't visible.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yqNcn/

Comment: Nice, jQuery UI demo copied, and its not working. I can only guess that jsfiddle messed up.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have not included the CSS for jQuery UI so classes are applied but *styles* are not (there are actually none to apply). [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/yqNcn/3/) an edited fiddle that includes the styles (look at the Resources panel); the slider is visible as it should be.

Comment: That is strange, jsfiddle doesn't take care of that even though you checked the jQuery UI checkbox? Thats either a bug or not really thought out... jQuery UI is more than JS code.

Comment: Great, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First Import your javascript Files* [jquery.s](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js) and import Jquery UI widget [Jquery-ui.js](http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js)
Then
Put Your Css **Div** Tag with **id** `<div id="slider"></div>` this Example

```
<div id="slider"></div>
```

then Call Jquery slider function....

```
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#slider" ).slider();
});
</script>
```